# R: How to Write a Function that Creates a Scatterplot of Two Variable Based Upon Value of Specified Third Variable

Tags: r, function, plot

I am new to R. I am trying to create a function (using Loblolly) that plots the Height and Age based upon a specified Seed number in the data. I don't know how one would go about setting this function up.

```
Loblolly

lob<-function (z){
z<-Loblolly$Seed
x<-Loblolly$age
y<-Loblolly$height
return(plot(x,y))
}
lob(301)
```

This is what I am getting:
[image]

This is what I would like to bet getting:
[image]

Comment: (1) Writing a function that relies on the presence of variables not passed explicitly to it is scope-breach, is against programming best practices, and will make testing, troubleshooting, and maintaining almost untenable in the long hall. Explicitly pass or define all required data/values. (2) You pass `z`, immediately overwrite it, and never use it. (3) You are asking a question as if this code does not do something. What is wrong with it? Any errors/warnings? Why is the plot (if created) not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
lob<-function (z){
x<-Loblolly$age
y<-Loblolly$height
return(plot(x[Loblolly$Seed == z],y[Loblolly$Seed == z],xlab="Age",ylab="Height"))
}
lob(323)
```

[image]